# I can't do basic login - can't find the object

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, authentication, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to do a basic login to a website, but I can't reach 2 objects :

The password field and the button.

The website is: https://www.cms.co.il/default.aspx

I have tried to find element by `id` or by `class` - or by `XPATH` , and I'm finding the `"login"` text box - but not the "password".

I have checked the name of the attr:

```
print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input#password.top_field.w-input").get_attribute("name"))

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(LOGIN_URL)
driver.find_element_by_id("login").clear()
driver.find_element_by_id("login").send_keys(login)
driver.find_element_by_id("password").click()
driver.find_element_by_class_name("top_field w-input").click()
```

Also, I'm have tried this:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input#password.top_field.w-input").send_keys(password)
```

driver.find_element_by_class_name("top_button.w-button").click()

but it still can't reach the password field

What I'm a doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The element have 2 classes, so you have to replace the space with <kbd>.</kbd> in your code.

You have to use the below line.

```
# password 
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input#password.top_field.w-input").send_keys('hello')
# click on button
driver.find_element_by_class_name("top_button.w-button").click()
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: hi - im getting error :      selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=76.0.3809.132)

Comment: my code is:        
driver = webdriver.Chrome()    
driver.get(LOGIN_URL)    
driver.find_element_by_id("login").clear()    
driver.find_element_by_id("login").send_keys(login)   
driver.find_element_by_id("login").send_keys(Keys.TAB)   
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input#password.top_field.w-input

Comment: Which line is giving the `ElementNotInteractableException`?

Answer (score 0):

solved it ! :)

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(LOGIN_URL)
driver.find_element_by_id("login").clear()
driver.find_element_by_id("login").send_keys(login)
driver.find_element_by_id("login").send_keys(Keys.TAB)
time.sleep(3)
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.send_keys(password)
actions.perform()
driver.find_element_by_class_name("top_button.w-button").click()
```

Comment: Try not to use Sleeps in your code. Better to use explicit waits.